# Page not scaling correctly in window mode

Tags: css, scaling

I'm having some isues with my homepage -> http://holtumdata.dk/mission
After I fixed som scaling problems in regards to your PC's resolution, am I getting a new issue. Whenever I click from full screen to a window instead, the scaling is weird again, and the text isn't placed right.

What should I do to fix that?

You can see the issue by going to http://holtumdata.dk/mission
And then change from full screen to window mode in your browser. (Try pulling to different sizes to see how it changes.)

Thanks!

```
   */
.blog #content {
  margin-left: 100px;
padding: 0 0 1.53846153846154em 0;
  background-color: transparent;
}
@media screen and (min-device-width: 1920px) {
#content {
  margin-bottom: 1.53846153846154em;
  margin-left: -21em;
} }
@media screen and (min-device-width: 1600px) and (max-device-width: 1919px)  {
#content {
  margin-bottom: 1.53846153846154em;
  margin-left: -11.5em;
} }
@media screen and (min-device-width: 1440px) and (max-device-width: 1599px)  {
#content {
  margin-bottom: 1.53846153846154em;
  margin-left: -2em;
} }
@media screen and (max-device-width: 1439px) {
#content {
  margin-bottom: 1.53846153846154em;
} }
.single #content {
padding: 0;
}
.page-template-gallery-fullscreen-php #content {
display: none;
}
```

Code added above.

Comment: Post the code and css part where you set the content and its style

Comment: Add the css where you set your containers (head,content,footer) as it looks like you are using some properties wrong getting these issues

Comment: I've added it under .blog #content to only make it apply on those pages. It isn't supposed to change on other pages, because I only have had issues on my blog pages.

Comment: Setting negative margin like that, make me think your setup has a not so good approach having content centered on the page. It's rare that a negative margin like that should be needed, making me wonder, is your content placeholder set with fixed widths and/or absolute positioning?

Comment: I just noticed in your "style.css" that you use a "two-columns, fixed-width" template. I would suggest a fluent layout, though they might be trickier to use but will likely pay off when targeting so many different device resolutions available.

Comment: My content is set with a fixed margin, because it's located longer in on the side normally.

Answer (score 0):

I found this:

```
@media screen and (min-device-width: 1920px)
    #content {
    margin-bottom: 1.53846153846154em;
    margin-left: -21em;
}
```

Setting the `margin-left` to `0` will fix the issue.

Comment: If I set the margin to 0 the scaling will be wrong when in full window mode :-)

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem seems to be that you do not consider screen sizes in the size of the small window. So basically you need to add another @media screen tag in your css for displays as small as the small windows. Mobile users will experience the same thing happening to the text if you do not consider their screen size, too